# fields_view_get does not exist in Odoo 16

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-16

I was testing the modules of Odoo 15 that I developed in Odoo 16, I was using a lot of the method `fields_views_get` to have some behaviors to inject domain and context, before to render the component, but currently I can not find this method.

Someone here knows what will be the alternative to achieve some behavior in runtime (modify the XML with the `etree` component of `lxml`)?

The main goal here is to inject in the XML data that is very difficult to add without the `env` object since with the `fields_views_get` I was able to inject or make queries before returning the XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fields_view_get` was renamed to `get_view`:

> `fields_view_get` becomes `get_view`.
> As it no longer returns the fields description,
> keeping the `fields` in the name `fields_view_get` no longer makes sense.
> Hence removing `fields` from the method name, it becomes `view_get`.
> As it gets renamed anyway, we take the opportunity to rename it `get_view`,
> which is more in line with the general getter/setter guidelines
> in the model object world.
> - `_fields_view_get` becomes `_get_view`. For the same reasons than above.
> - `load_views` becomes `get_views`.

You can find more details in [refactor fields_view_get, load_views](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/b03c227e885efa4ccdcad43ccb56ee10371b9284#)  commit

In the changed files, you can see an example of commit diff of [res_users](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/b03c227e885efa4ccdcad43ccb56ee10371b9284#diff-066984e34556783cf7d6a4f2aace7eb43d08899fceba167f2131109bd6600855L169) model which replaces:

```
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
```

With:

```
def get_view(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', **options):
```

Comment: i tried using get_view, get_views and _get_view but only _get_view renders readonly attr the other add the attr but without effect can you please help

Comment: Try to provide enough details to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

the method fields_views_get has been renamed to get_view in Odoo 16.0. This method returns the fields_views of given views, along with the fields of the current model, and optionally its filters for the given action. You can use this method to modify the XML view before rendering it, just like you did with fields_views_get in Odoo 15.0.

For example, if you want to inject a domain and a context to a field in a form view, you can override the get_view method in your model and use the etree component of lxml to manipulate the XML view. Here is a sample code:

```
from odoo import models
from lxml import etree
    
class TestModel(models.Model):
    _name = "test.model"
    _inherit = "test.model"
    
    def get_view(self, views, options=None):
    # call super to get the original view
    result = super().get_view(views, options)
    # loop through the views
    for view in result.get("fields_views", {}).values():
            # check if the view type is form
            if view["type"] == "form":
                # parse the XML view
                doc = etree.XML(view["arch"])
                # find the field that you want to modify
                field = doc.xpath("//field[@name='your_field_name']")
            if field:
                # inject your domain and context
                field[0].set("domain", "[('your_domain', '=', True)]")
                field[0].set("context", "{'your_context': 'value'}")
            # update the view arch with the modified XML
            view["arch"] = etree.tostring(doc, encoding="unicode")
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The above did not work for me though,
You can try this

```
@api.model
def get_view(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', **options):
     view = super().get_view(view_id, view_type, **options)
     if view_type == 'form':
            doc = etree.XML(view["arch"])
            # find the field that you want to modify
            field = doc.xpath("//field[@name='morning_ids']")
            print(field)
            if field:
                teacher = self.env['sm.teacher'].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.user.id)], limit=1)
                # teacher = self.env.user.teacher_id
                if teacher:
                    # Filter students based on the teacher's class
                    students = self.env['sm.student'].search([('class_id', '=', teacher.class_id.id)])
                    student_ids =  students.ids
                    # inject your domain and context
                    domain_value = True  # Set your variable here
                    domain = "[('id', '=', %s)]" % student_ids
                    field[0].set("domain", domain)
                    field_string = etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True)
                    # Print the string representation of the Element
                    print(field_string)
            # update the view arch with the modified XML
            view["arch"] = etree.tostring(doc, encoding="unicode")
     return view
i was trying to update the morning_ids, i need to check if the login user is a teacher, and then fetch all the students, that are in the class the teacher is in charge of, and the above code work fine
```